# List of Domains offering Web-mail services

Tags: web-services, networking, web-api, http-request

I want to maintain a list of domain names that provide web-mail services.

I searched and received a list of 1634 domains([Free Public web-mail services](http://www.0spam.com/freemail/))

However, is it possible to get updates, if any new domain registers to offer web-mail service,through scripts or through tools.

Or, is it possible to tell by looking at domain name in the http header (through scripts/tools), whether it is offering web-mail service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question - no, it isn't feasible to automatically scan for webmail providers.

A web mail provider is simply a web application. It doesn't follow any specific standard or expose a specific interface. It's just a web site with functionality.

- It can be mostly server-side or have client-side elements.
- It can be written in [PHP](http://squirrelmail.org/about/), or [ASP.NET](http://www.afterlogic.org/webmail-lite-net), or in native C++ via a CGI gateway.
- It can be hosted, like Gmail or Yahoo mail, or it might be a software package that's installed on thousands of different servers - you can install SquirrelMail on your own cheap $5/mo PHP hosting.
- It can supply web-based services for the general public, or to a specific group (universities, organizations, customers) or can be a private server.

So no, any hope to get a definitive list of all webmail service providers automatically is doomed to failure.